# Rails has many through association how to order by number of children?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to create an simple menu that is ordered by how many products that are in the category(tags)

Like:

```
Television (10)
Toothpase  (5)
Computer   (3)
```

My controller:

```
def tags
  @tags = Tag.all
end
```

My view:

```
<% @tags.each do |tags| %>
  <li><%= tags.name %>    <%= tags.konkurrancers.count %></li>
<% end %>
```

My model:

```
has_many :konkurrancers, :through => :tagsmenus
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def tags
  @tags = Tag.all.sort_by{|t| -t.konkurrancers.count }
end
```

If you do this proves to be too slow you should add a counter_cache column (named children_count) to the tags table for speed, so you can then do this:

```
def tags
  @tags = Tag.all(:order => 'children_count DESC')
end
```

Comment: Thanks the only problem is the that is the wrong direction how do i make order ny DECS

Comment: How to create the counter cache column? I have searched the internet and found this http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column but it is not rails 3

Comment: I found a solution how to reverse the order: Tag.all.sort_by{|t| t.konkurrancers.count }.reverse

Comment: Re: the counter_cache column; the instructions are the same for Rails 2 and 3. Also, try Tag.all.sort_by{|t| -t.koncurrancers.count } to reverse the sort without doubling the objects created in memory